# Why does date formatting sometimes not work in Debugger?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-debugging

I am puzzled. Tried to check some program data during a debug session and stumbled upon this. Everything is basically on the picture:

[image]

Date formatting appears to be not working when used with Linq extensions in the Debugger's 'Watch' window. Instead it seems to apply the default locale formatting for Dates. The same code, when put in a program, works perfectly, as well as basic DateTime formatting in the row above.

What am I missing?

Comment: Bizarre find.  I can reproduce this on VS2019 v16.5.0 in the `en-US` culture.  Your original expression as well as substituting `.First()` or `.ToList()[0]` for `.ToList()` all evaluate to `"3/19/2020 12:36:48 AM"`.  Using a standard format string makes no difference, either.  `new List<DateTime>() {DateTime.Now}.Select(d => {var s = d.ToString("HH:mm"); return s.Substring(0, 5);}).ToList()` evaluates to `"3/19/"`.  If I define `static string FormatTime(DateTime d) => d.ToString("HH:mm");` and add a watch with `.Select(FormatTime).ToList()` even that doesn't work!

Comment: I'm a bit suprised that a Linq expression (aka an anonymous function) works in the debugger watch window at all. Last time I used VS, they didn't have that feature yet -- because it requires a compiler. And trying to compile and inject code into a running process while in the middle of debugging is a rather tricky thing to do. Perhaps there are simply some limitations of what it can do?

Comment: @Vilx- IIRC Linq expressions worked with Watch/Immediate windows from the time they appeared in .NET. It requires having `using System.Linq` in your current context, otherwise you will have to write weird expressions in order to make extensions work. I don't see much difference in evaluating a Linq expression as opposed to any other expression. Also I don't see much sense in "aka an anonymous function". Linq expressions may or MAY NOT use lambdas.

Comment: In general, yes, but in this particular case the `Select()` function takes a callback function. This means that the IDE needs to compile your lambda expression into a function and then pass that to the `Select()` method. Well, it could be that I'm remembering wrong (it's been some time since I last worked with .NET), but in my mind there's a memory that says I can't use lambda expressions in Inspect/Watch windows.

Comment: Interestingly, I also tried `new List<int> { 12345 }.Select(i => i.ToString("N2")).ToList()` and the `Watch` window evaluated it to the expected `"12,345.00"`.  @Vilx- Debugger support for lambda expressions was added in Visual Studio 2015.  See [Support for debugging lambda expressions with Visual Studio 2015](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/support-for-debugging-lambda-expressions-with-visual-studio-2015/) and [Better together: C# 6 and the Visual Studio 2015 Debugger](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/better-together-c-6-and-the-visual-studio-2015-debugger/).

Comment: What happens on `d=>d.ToString("HH:mm")+"xxx"`? Do you see the `"xxx"`?

Comment: @Vilx- Like my `Substring()` example above, I do see the `string` manipulation is performed but it's applied to the `DateTime` formatted with the `G` format specifier (like the parameterless overload of `DateTime.ToString()`), not the `HH:mm` specifier.  Thus, the `Watch` window shows `"3/20/2020 2:02:56 PMxxx"`.

Comment: OK, this is really, really weird! Congratulations, you've found a special edge case!

Comment: FYI, I reported it as a bug using Help -> Send Feedback -> Report a Problem. I am not sure if the report can be accessed publicly though...

Comment: I don't know if it's connected to what you submitted, but there's a recent problem report on [Visual Studio Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/): [Date formatting string does not work in the Debuggers's 'Watch' window](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/956003/date-formatting-string-does-not-work-in-the-debugg.html)

Comment: Yep, it's mine, thanks!